# Vaadin Grid and initially sorted data

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

I have a Grid component with Indexed container where data is sorted initially into two columns (the data comes from Elasticsearch). How can I tell Grid to know about this sorting and then show proper sorting icons in column headings when Grid is loaded?

**EDIT #1**
I tried to redefine Grids  `public List<SortOrder> getSortOrder()` method to return proper sorting data, but it doesnt work ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't shown much code so I'll have to assume you're using the default Indexed container and then add columns like `grid.addColumn("c1", String.class);`. If that's true, then it looks like you can't supply your own container implementation because vaadin will throw an exception when providing a different container and adding columns (haven't had the time to figure out why):

```
protected void addColumnProperty(Object propertyId, Class<?> type, Object defaultValue) throws IllegalStateException {
    if(!this.defaultContainer) {
        throw new IllegalStateException("Container for this Grid is not a default container from Grid() constructor");
```

In this case, you can probably create your own Grid implementation which bypasses the issue, or you could use a bean item container like in the example below, where you overwrite the `doSort` method to do nothing:

```
BeanItemContainer<MyBean> dataSource = new BeanItemContainer<MyBean>(MyBean.class) {
    @Override
    protected void doSort() {
        // nop, data is already sorted
    }
};
Grid grid = new Grid(dataSource);
```

Then simply call the `setSortOrder` method on the grid.

```
import com.vaadin.data.sort.Sort;
import com.vaadin.shared.data.sort.SortDirection;
...
grid.setSortOrder(Sort.by("c3", SortDirection.ASCENDING).then("c2", SortDirection.DESCENDING).build());
```

Which results in column c3 being sorted ascending first, and then c2 descending (see the numbers near the sorting icon):

[image: sorting sample]

Please note that the column headers will still be clickable so the sorting icons will change and events will be triggered, but nothing will happen because the `doSort` was overwritten. You will probably need to react to this so you can add a sortListener and request a new batch of data, sorted according to the user selection:

```
grid.addSortListener(new SortEvent.SortListener() {
    @Override
    public void sort(SortEvent sortEvent) {
        // request data sorted according to the user selection
    }
});
```

Comment: Yeah I know this but it calls Container.sort() method so it forces container to sort it once again. So its not what I mean because data are sorted already from Elasticsearch.

Comment: Great, its exactly what I need and it works. I moved my code from Container.sort() method to SortListener and override Container.sort() as empty. Now its working exctly as needed.

Comment: @DavidMarko Great, glad it worked out eventually. Cheers

Comment: how to remove those numbers from column header

Comment: @AnujVictor it's been a while since I answered this question so I no longer have the code at hand for a quick reply. I suspect you could do this via CSS, but I suggest you open a new question for this (after searching to see if no other such question exists), with the relevant code, what you tried and where you got stuck.

Comment: @Morfic thanx for the reply, but i sorted the list only, not the grid. So my problem got solved